# Applying for a Ukranian multiple-entry visa, how should I fill in the application?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, ukraine

I am an Indian citizen. I want to apply for multiple entry visa of Ukraine for one year but I have few doubts regarding form filling.

1. I want to go to Ukraine for three times within one year but for different duration ( 1st time for 10 days, again after few months for 15 days, again after few months for 22 days)  so what should I write in the row **"Duration of the intended stay or transit Indicate number of days"** , total = 10+15+22= 47 days or 90 days(According 90/180 rule) or 365 days (as I want visa for 1 year)  ?
2. What should I write in the row **"Intended date of departure from Ukraine"**, should I write my  first trip departure date from Ukraine or  3rd (last) trip departure date from Ukraine ?

**N.B. Earlier,it was used to be physical form but now details have to be filled online.**

Comment: 90 days(According 90/180 rule) -- that is a Schengen rule, not quite sure how would it apply here.

Comment: Duration of intended stay is indeed 47 days.

Answer (score 2):

As duration of the intended stay you should put the total number of days you plan on staying in Ukraine, summing over all your planned trips: 47 days. The intended departure from Ukraine should probably be the date of your first trip. Then, since you are asking for a multiple entry visa, you should attach detailed plans - proof of accomodation, proof of travel, proof of funds, etc - of your successive travels to justify that request.